# problema com espaçamento e começando com número

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma aplicação onde tem uma tela com um EditText e um botão.
quando pressiono o botão pego a String do EditText jogo numa coluna do Banco de Dados na tabela tabelas, e logo em seguida Crio uma nova tabela do banco de dados com o nome que o usuário escolheu.

**Quando o usuário usa espaço da erro ao iniciar a tabela.** 
**Quando o usuário usa numero para começar o nome da erro ao iniciar a tabela**

Um outro detalhe é que em outra activity eu uso o nome da tabela para mostrar na action Bar.
passo o nome da tabela utilizada por um bundle, e na outra activity abro o banco com o nome passado e trabalho com ele.

```
public class adcionartabela extends ActionBarActivity {
//inicia variaveis
SQLiteDatabase Banco = null;
Cursor cursor;
String tabela; 
EditText escrevetabela;
Button ok;
@Override

//TODO oncreate
//começa o oncreate
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editable);


    //inicializa objetos
    escrevetabela    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTexttabela);
    ok               = (Button)   findViewById(R.id.buttonok);


    abrebanco();

    //TODO botão ok
    //seta função do botão OK
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            insert       (escrevetabela.getText().toString());
            abrebanco2   (escrevetabela.getText().toString());
            iniciartabela(escrevetabela.getText().toString());
            fechabanco();
            Intent intent = new Intent(adcionartabela.this,gerenciar.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            adcionartabela.this.finish();   
        }


    });


}

//TODO iniciartabela
//inicia tabela no banco de dados, cria todos os IDs necessários
public void iniciartabela(String tabbanco) {
    for(int x = 0 ;x<60;x++)
    {   try{
        String sql = "INSERT INTO "+tabbanco+" (bt,bt01,bt02,bt03,bt04,bt05," +
                "bt06,bt07,bt08,bt09,bt10," +
                "bt11,bt12,bt13,bt14,bt15) " +
                "values ('','','','',''," +
                "'','','','','','','','','','','') ";
        Banco.execSQL(sql);
    }
    catch(Exception erro){};
    }

}

//TODO abrebanco2
//cria tabela nova
public void abrebanco2(String tabbanco){
    try{
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+tabbanco+" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" +
                ", bt TEXT,bt01 TEXT, bt02 TEXT, bt03 TEXT, bt04 TEXT, bt05 TEXT, bt06 TEXT, " +
                "bt07 TEXT, bt08 TEXT, bt09 TEXT, bt10 TEXT, bt11 TEXT, bt12 TEXT, " +
                "bt13 TEXT, bt14 TEXT, bt15 TEXT)";
        Banco.execSQL(sql);

    }
    catch(Exception erro){
        Exibirmensagem("BANCO", "erro ao criar banco: =/"+ erro.getMessage(), "ok");
    }
}
```

é preferível maquiar isso do que bloquear ao usuário, porem a segunda também é válida.
a grande pergunta como é que eu trato uma String para salvar no banco de dados corretamente, ou enviar um alerta ao usuário que ele colocou um nome inválido?
como vocês me aconselhariam fazer essa otimização sem danificar o funcionamento do aplicativo?

Comment: Uma forma de fazer: quando o usuário clicar no botão de criar a tabela, valide a string inserida pelo usuário usando um _regex_ (expressão regular) e, caso não seja válida, não deixe a tabela ser criada; ao invés disso exiba um _toast_ informando que o nome fornecido é inválido.

Comment: @Piovezan , você teria um exemplo de como usar esse regex? o eclipse não esta reconhecendo

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo como resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A expressão regular abaixo obriga o nome da tabela a começar com uma letra ou *underscore* (`_`) seguido por outros caracteres que podem ser letras, números, *underscores* ou hífens.

```
if (escrevetabela.getText().matches("^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_\-]+$") {
   // Cria tabela
} else {
   // Exibe toast informando que o nome digitado é inválido
}
```

Se quiser um outro formato de nome, procure estudar a [sintaxe de expressões regulares](http://www.devmedia.com.br/conceitos-basicos-sobre-expressoes-regulares-em-java/27539).